# Linq to selectmany with distinct values of a variable from IGrouping

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use LINQ and I need some help with lambda expressions .

I have an `IGrouping<DateTime, Option>`. The `Option` class has multiple variables like `Price`, `Root`, etc.

I am trying to select only  those `Option` objects in a `foreach` with distinct `Root` values and I am not sure how to get it. I tried doing like this:

```
IGrouping<DateTime, Option> optvalues;
foreach (var symbol in optvalues.SelectMany(t => t.Root.Distinct()))
{ 
    //This is returning some random value “85 S” in rootdiff.
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `Root`?

Comment: its a string @khoroshevj

Comment: So `Root.Distinct()` treats the string as an `IEnumerable<char>` and returns the distinct characters in `Root` :) (Types are very important in C#.)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), namely a console app with code that others can *run*. You are missing the input to illustrate how this isn't producing the output you expect, as well as an adequate description of what that expectation is.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need `DistinctBy`:

```
foreach (var symbol in optvalues.DistinctBy(opt => opt.Root)) {
}
```

which is an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, TKey> keyFun) {
    //      return src.GroupBy(keyFun).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());  // to defer execution
    var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (T e in src)
        if (seenKeys.Add(keyFun(e)))
            yield return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just applied `Distinct` to the wrong value

```
IGrouping<DateTime, Option> optvalues;
foreach (var symbol in optvalues.SelectMany(t => t).Select(t => t.Root).Distinct())
{ 
    //
}
```

Comment: This result is the same as what I got. 85 'S'

Comment: Since `t.Root` is type `string`, `SelectMany` doesn't make sense - it the result is `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (var symbol in optvalues.Select(t => r.Root).Distinct())
    { 
       //...
    }
```

Comment: Better, but he wants to select the `Option` objects, not the `Root` values.